# Converting file descriptor (pipe) to file object in python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'd like to use anonymous pipes to communicate pickled objects between two processes in linux. I don't want to use the `subprocess` module and instead manually create the necessary pipes and then call `pickle.dump` and `pickle.load`. The last two functions, however, require a file object. So, while testing things around, I was faced with the following problem. The following code works fine:

```
import os
r, w = os.pipe()
os.write(w, b"test")
os.read(r, 1024)
```

but this code stalls at the read operation

```
import os
r, w = os.pipe()
fr = os.fdopen(r, "rb")
fw = os.fdopen(w, "wb")
fw.write(b"test")
fr.read()
```

Additionally, `select.select([r],[],[],0)` shows the pipe is empty. My question: what is going on during file object creation and why doesn't it work for pipes? Is there a way to get a file object this way at all?

Comment: please always use the generic [python] tag when asking Python questions

Comment: Sure, will do in the future!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a combination of two problems. First, a file object created by `os.fdopen` is buffered by default. Either make it unbuffered:

```
fr = os.fdopen(r, "rb", buffering=0)
fw = os.fdopen(w, "wb", buffering=0)
```

Or flush the written data:

```
fw.write(b"test")
fw.flush()
```

Second, function `fr.read()` when called without parameters reads to the end of file. In the case of a pipe, it means, until the pipe is closed. You should pass the number of bytes you want to read:

```
fr.read(4)
> b'test'
```

If you are not sure how much data will be written, read it piecewise, N bytes per call, and then recombine.

Comment: Thank you, this makes a lot of sense (and is in the documentation for the built-in `open` which I should probably pay closer attention to :-))